# Is there any way to simplify this function with lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So I'll try to be descriptive as possible. I have a winforms app that is grouping machines on labels. I have working code but I was wondering if there was any other better way or more readable code that could do the same thing in less code?

So basically when the count reaches 23 I'm trying to reset it to 0 based on a column called count which is bitwise 1 or 0, when it is 1 the the labels will show only data with count 0.

```
        if (lbl1.Text == "23")
        {
            string sql = "update tbl_mch_ability set count = 1 where mchNo = 'Spot 1' ";
            con.OpenConnection();
            con.ExecuteQuery(sql);
        }
        else if (lbl2.Text == "23")
        {
            string sql = "update tbl_mch_ability set count = 1 where mchNo = 'Spot 2' ";
            con.OpenConnection();
            con.ExecuteQuery(sql);
        }
```

This works fine but I have more that 10 lbls and I was wondering if there was a more easier way to do this?

Comment: You don't need a lambda to simplify this. If you meant move the contents of each if block into a lambda then you could just do that with a regular method, not a lambda, but I think you can do better than that still. You could e.g. make a list of pairs of label and mchNo value, and loop over the list checking each label in turn and substituting that mchNo into your SQL string or a prepared query to execute. I'm not convinced that this is the right place to OpenConnection though, and an Update is definitely an ExecuteNonQuery since it doesn't return a table of data.

Comment: To simplfy it, you need to refactor repeated code out. Move the label checks into a function that returns the value your SQL statement needs, and concatenate it to the SQL statement. This is the easiest and cleanest way without using a list or a map

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! Still a newbie trying to get better

Comment: That's why we're here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that refactored with a lambda:

```
Action<Label, string, string> update = (label, trigger, mchNo) =>
{
  if ( label.Text == trigger )
  {
    string sql = $"update tbl_mch_ability set count = 1 where mchNo = '{mchNo}' ";
    con.OpenConnection();
    con.ExecuteQuery(sql);
  }
};

update(lbl1, "23", "Spot 1");
update(lbl2, "23", "Spot 2");
```

You should use sqlparameters to prevent injection as a good usual reflex practice.

Comment: I would reverse that logic i.e if not equal to trigger, return. Otherwise it looks good!